# В ubuntu глючит мышь

Tags: мышь, ubuntu

xubuntu 11.10 voyager при прокрутке колесика на беспроводной мыши она отключается и перестает отвечать на какие-либо действия. Есть предложения - в каком направлении смотреть?

p.s. На мышь не грешить, т.к. в семерке работает безупречно.

На проводной нет возможности проверить - сломано колесо.

Answer (score 2):

Мышь A4Tech ?С ними известные проблемы, попробуйте другую мышь.Если нет возможности, то напишите модель мыши сюда, я постараюсь вам помочь.

---

**добавлено из комментариев**

Попробуйте установить пакет *xserver-xorg-input-evdev*:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

и перезапустить x-сервер (например, завершив x-сеанс).

Comment: заменить нет возможности модель "a4tech g9-370fx" на версии убунтну 10.04 LTS без обновления системы и драйверов на видеокарту работает нормально, как только все обновил сразу появился этот глюк!

Comment: sudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get upgradesudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdevПробуйте, если что, можете написать мне в ICQ. 82о2о1о1

Answer (score 1):

У меня был похожий глюк и оказалась проблема в драйверах для видеокарты. Пришлось поставить версию чуть по-старее и проблема решилась!

Comment: Вот к такому выводу я пришел буквально вчера, обновил драйвера на видюшку и после ребута повисла мышь, а можешь подсказать как откатить версию до более старой?

Answer (score 0):

Заменить драйвер мыши.

**Обновление**

К сожалению, не силен в УБУНТУ (чем-то он мне не понравился когда еще только линуксятничать начинал, давно это было и не помню чем именно), но думаю, что управление этим процессом должно быть где-то в управлении оборудованием, в частности, в openSUSE (которым пользуюсь я и очень этим доволен) это находится в центре управления YAST - Оборудование. Там можно выбрать тип используемой мыши (ну или подобрать более нормально работающий).

Comment: А как это осуществить? я линукс только осваиваю.К стати проверил проводную мышь - та же беда, тоже отключается. так же не работает горячее включение usb мыши и клавиатуры, и если вытащить то назад уже не подключится, так же если подключено несколько грызунов, работают все, одну если вытащить то перестают отвечать все остальные. может есть какой-нибудь драйвер для usb, который можно заменить или поковырять?